# How to test class a public Page reference with String

Tags: apex, unit-test

**CLASS**

### I dont know why the emphasis lines below didnt covered by my test class someone please help me. the test class below i just a part of my test class so this proceedToLogin are the class in my class didnt been covered.

```
 public PageReference ProceedToLogin(){
 String fromAccount = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ex');

 *if (fromAccount == 'acct'){
 PageReference pr = Page.GHI_Portal_Account;
 pr.setRedirect(true);
 return pr;*

 } else {

    PageReference pr = Page.GHI_Portal_Login;
    pr.setRedirect(true);

    return pr;
    }
}
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
    PageReference prs2 = Page.GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Step2;
    prs2.getParameters().put('un', testUser.Username);
    Test.setCurrentPage(prs2);GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller controller = new    GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller();
    controller = new GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller()
    controller.proceedToLogin();
```

Comment: Hi there - can you provide more clarity sorry.

Comment: (fromAccount == 'acct') i dont know how can  i make this true so the if statement will be covered

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
PageReference prs2 = Page.GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Step2;
prs2.getParameters().put('un', testUser.Username);
prs2.getParameters().put('ex', 'acct');
Test.setCurrentPage(prs2);
GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller controller = new GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller();
controller = new GHI_Portal_PasswordReset_Controller()
controller.proceedToLogin();
```

Comment: @Mheljun..is this working?